# CIS benchmark differences between 2008R2 to 2012R2

Tags: group-policy, benchmark, hardening

I'm looking at hardening our golden image inline with the CIS benchmarks for Windows Server 2008R2 and 2012R2. But, after looking at the two benchmark [documents](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/benchmarks/)(registration required - sorry) from CIS, the 2008 document format is different and larger so its difficult to know how to tackle this comparison in a time effective manner?

Do you have any ideas on how to compare the 2008 and 2012 benchmarks and deal with differences?

Comment: You don't really need registration

Answer (score 0):

Excel points made out of the two of them, make an 1:1 comparison for the points that are the same, add everything that you have more on 2012r2 as an separate project , profit!

Comment: Interesting answer, if you can elaborate on some points that will help me. I.e. Is it possible to easily convert the pdf documents into "excel points"?

Comment: I'm afraid this will take some time and it is really subjective for the environment.

Comment: I'm affraid you'd say that. Guess I'll have to bite the bullet and start the long task of comparing a 600 page document. :<